# How to calculate in_features for every layer in multilayer perceptron?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, perceptron

What ratio between in_features of different layers is appropriate? Should it be integer?
For example, it is a part of the fully connected network for solving CIFAR10:

```
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(32*32*3, 256)
self.bn1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(256)
self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 64)
self.bn2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 10)
```

Why does an author in the tutorial uses 256 nodes in the second layer and 64 in the third? Or there could be absolutely different numbers?

Comment: Hi @Victoria, welcome to the community. Your question might need a little bit of context and clarification to get the best attention from the community. To begin with: What tutorial are you referencing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually in the classification case with mlp (I'm talking about the really common case), you put numbers between the entry and output sizes at each layer.
Here entry (pixels of images): 32x32x3 = 3072 to output (classes) : 10

Often power of 2 are used (probably for efficiency) but you could have used 1000 and 200 as long as it works. Even if there is some other general rules, as long as it works with neural networks ...